# Adding an item to an array as long as the item isn't already in there and the array isn't full

Tags: java, arrays, equals

My requirement is to make a course registration for students and faculty.
My problem is adding the student to the array as long as the student isn't already in the array, and the array isn't full. I've been working on this all day so it looks mangled, any help or a point in the right direction is appreciated. Thank you.

This is my course java file:

```
package registration;

public class Course{

    private String department;
    private String courseName;
    private int maxSize;
    private int currentEnrollmentNumber;
    private Student roster[];
    private Faculty facultyInstructor;
    
    public Course(String department, String courseName, int maxSize) {
        this.department = department;
        this.courseName = courseName;
        this.setMaxSize(maxSize);
        setCurrentEnrollmentNumber(0);
        roster = new Student[maxSize];
    }
    
    void assignInstructor(Faculty f) {
        if(f.getDepartment().equals(department)) {
            facultyInstructor = f;
            System.out.println(f.getName() + " has been assigned to teach this course");
        }else {
            System.out.println(f.getName() + " cannot be assigned to this course. Only faculties from " + department + " department can be assigned to teach this course.");
        }
    }
    
    void addStudent(Student s) {
        do {
            roster[currentEnrollmentNumber] = s;
            System.out.println(s.getName() + " has been added to the course");
            for (int i = currentEnrollmentNumber; i < maxSize; i++) {
            }

        } while (!s.equals(roster[currentEnrollmentNumber]));
        
//      if (currentEnrollmentNumber < maxSize && )) {
//              roster[currentEnrollmentNumber] = s;
//              System.out.println(s.getName() + " has been added to the course");
//              currentEnrollmentNumber++;
    }// System.out.println(s.getName() + " is already registered");
```

This is the student Java file:

```
package registration;

public class Student extends Person {
        private String major;
        private double gpa;
        
        Student(){
            
        }
        
        Student(String name, int age, String email, String major, double gpa){
            super(name, age, email);
            this.major = major; 
            this.gpa = gpa;
        }
        
        void registerForCourse(Course c) {
            if(c.getMaxSize() <= c.getCurrentEnrollmentNumber()) {
                System.out.println("Class is at maximum capacity");
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < c.getCurrentEnrollmentNumber(); i++) {
                if(c.getRoster()[i].equals(this)) {
                    return;
                }
            }
            c.getRoster()[c.getCurrentEnrollmentNumber()] = this;
            c.setCurrentEnrollmentNumber(c.getCurrentEnrollmentNumber() + 1);
        } 
        
        public boolean equals(Object otherObject) {
            if(otherObject == null) {
                return false;
            } else {
                if(getClass() == otherObject.getClass()) {
                    Student otherStudent = (Student)otherObject;
                    return (getName().equals(otherStudent.getName()) && getAge() == otherStudent.getAge() && getEmail().equals(otherStudent.getEmail()));
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        
        public boolean equals(Student otherStudent) {
            return super.equals(otherStudent) && getMajor().equals(otherStudent.major) && getGpa() == otherStudent.gpa;
        }
```

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157)

Comment: Seems pretty straight forward. You have all the pieces, you just need to put them together. Think about all the things that need to happen and then put them in order.  Write it down on paper if you need to. Then code it.

Comment: Also I don't think the student need to know anything about the currentEnrollmentNumber. You don't need to do all that in the registerForCourse(). All the logic to register should be in the Course addStudent()

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to StackOverflow!  Your current method does indeed feel weird and confusing, let's get that sorted.

First,  perform your if loop to go through all current students and see if the student is already enrolled.  If they are, print the appropriate message and immediately invoke `return` to close the method down.  There is no need to process anything else.

If the student is not already enrolled, find out if there is space to add them.

If there is no more space, print the appropriate message and `return`.

If there is space for this student, go ahead and add them :)

Consider breaking some of this into separate methods, e.g. boolean isStudentAlreadyEnrolled(Student student), void enrollStudent(Student student).  Breaking down your code into smaller steps can help a lot with making it more readable, more testable and more reusable.

Comment: plus one for acknowledging this is homework and _helping_ the student solve the problem rather then give them the answer.